# Add necessary spaces in Python code

Tags: python

Is there any way to automatically format Python code, within Python? So, say for example, I have a string `x` which equals

```
if 5 < 7:
print "Yes"
else:
print "No"
```

and I want to run `exec(x)`, but obviously it'll throw an error because the syntax is incorrect, so is there a way I can change `x` to

```
if 5 < 7:
    print "Yes"
else:
    print "No"
```

and when I run `exec(x)` it would work?
Sorry for my bad English, it's a second language.

Comment: Whats the use case?

Comment: I'll hazard a guess that the answer is, in short: "no"

Comment: he is blind? Only possible case I can come up with.

Comment: some text editors have an automatic indentation option, so if you select python they will automatically indent after a condition, loop, function definition (or anything that needs indentation). Take in account however that they cannot do magic, so a line may be correct either indented or not but the execution will completely change.

Comment: `for x in y: if z: bar(); else: baz()` – Good luck indenting that correctly automatically… (hint, the `else` may belong to either the `for` or `if`, you simply don't know *without indentation*)

Comment: Might be trying to bulk convert from a different language?

Comment: *"Add __necessary__ spaces …"* – There's a reason they're *necessary*… :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following input:

```
if x == 1:
if y == 2:
print 'foo'
else:
print 'bar'
```

How should your programmatic solution indent the `else` block?

Like this?

```
if x == 1:
    if y == 2:
        print 'foo'
    else:
        print 'bar'
```

Or like this?

```
if x == 1:
    if y == 2:
        print 'foo'
else:
    print 'bar'
```

Indentation changes the meaning of the program.  It is the job of the programmer to decide what he means, not the computer.

Comment: With that said (somewhat academically), is there always a "least indented" valid python code? In this case your second example. I think not?

Comment: @Jonas Probably yes, but whether that result has anything to do with the original input nobody knows…

Answer (score 2):

In python indents are crucial. You can't allow code fixes to set them instead of a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

For this, it all depends on the IDE you are using. If you use JetBrains Pycharm, you can format the code using a command.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformatting-source-code.html

Please let me know what IDE you are using and I may be able to find the command you need to run.

Good luck,
Jordan

Edit:

The reason why your code will not run, is because of indentation. As the code is expecting a indent the line for print, it needs the command to complete, once you return to the same level of indentation, it expects that if 3 >7 to be finished with.

Answer (score 1):

By using autopep8, you can automatically format your code in the pep8 format, check it out.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8

Comment: I like to bind this to a key so I can format my code with a single keypress